# Copy all files with specific extension from remote server with Java

Tags: java, jsch

Hey everybody I'm trying to create a small script that will let me copy all files with a specific extension from a remote linux machine to my local machine through sftp.

This is the code I have so far, which lets me copy one file from the remote machine to my local machine, using Jsch, if I give the full path.

```
package transfer;

import com.jcraft.jsch.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CopyFromServer {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter the hostname or ip of the server on which the ctk files can be found: ");
        String hostname = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter your username: ");
        String username = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter your password: ");
        String password = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter the location where your files can be found: ");
        String copyFrom = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter the location where you want to place your files: ");
        String copyTo = sc.nextLine();

        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = jsch.getSession(username, hostname, 22);
            session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setPassword(password);
            session.connect();

            Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
            channel.connect();
            ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;

            sftpChannel.get(copyFrom, copyTo);
            sftpChannel.exit();
            session.disconnect();
        } catch (JSchException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  
        } catch (SftpException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like all of the files that have the extension ".jpg" in a specific folder to be copied and place in a folder the user defines.

I've tried:

```
sftpChannel.get(copyFrom + "*.jpg", copyTo);
```

Which did not work, I know I should use something like:

```
pathname.getName().endsWith("." + fileType)
```

But I'm not sure how to implement it with sftpChannel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `sftpChannel.ls("Path to dir");` which will returns list of files in the given path as a vector and you have to iterate on the vector to download each file `sftpChannel.get();`

```
Vector<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> list = sftpChannel .ls("."); 
    // iterate through objects in list, and check for extension
    for (ChannelSftp.LsEntry listEntry : list) {
            sftpChannel.get(listEntry.getFilename(), "fileName"); 

        }
    }
```

Comment: In your ls command you have to specify the directory path which you have to search for the files in remote location, not the file pattern and what about your copyFrom is that a directory??can you paste here the original string for that also??

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I figured it out. I placed copyFrom which is the folder where the files can be found on the sftp server where I should have placed copyTo the folder onto which the files should be copied. This works now. Thank you for your help :)